# Why is there an error when using discord.js v12 to send messages to players?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js v12 and I'm using `bot.users.cache.get('<ID>').send('<Message>');` to send a message, but it give an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. Anyone know how I might fix this?

Comment: It means that bot.users.cache is undefined, i.e it does not exist. If that helps you to debug. The error message states that .get() does not exist for undefined, hence bot.users.cache must be undefined in this case.

Comment: Right I get that so does that mean I have to initialize it in the beginning or something? It works when the person with the targeted ID runs the command but not when someone else does it.